# Microsoft Practices Unity - How do I tell Unity to look for assemblies in specific folder?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using web.config to load loosely coupled assemblies. I have a couple of 'dll' projects in my solution and I want to output all of them in a common folder. I want to tell Unity when resolving the types, to also look into that folder for the assemblies.

How do I do that?

Comment: Unity does not explicitly load any assemblies -- the CLR is responsible for loading assemblies.  See [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx) for a description of that process.  You will probably want to look at codeBase or probing elements to configure an alternate location.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't Unity ask the CLR to load an assembly, when it reads the web.config values, triggered by container.LoadConfiguration()? So, question is, how do I tell Visual Studio / CLR / Unity to not just look into the current 'bin' folder, but also in an additional folder? Ideally, there is a place in the web.config of my MVC app where I can specify such an 'additional' folder.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/chrismoseley/shared-assemblies-without-the-gac - basically this, but I don't want to <add assembly="Shared.Assembly.Name"/>, because then I lose the concept of loose coupling. That would be the same as referencing the dll in my project

Comment: Nevermind, i will just use post-build commands to copy the DLLs into the bin